# How to jump between frames in jCarousel immediately while in Autoscroll mode

Tags: jquery, pagination, jcarousel

I am using [Sorgalla's jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/).

I want the carousel to move steadily without interruption, so I initialized the jCarousel like:

```
$('.jcarousel').jcarousel({
    wrap: 'circular',
    animation: {
        duration: 5000,
        easing:   'linear',
    }
})
.jcarouselAutoscroll({
    target: '+=1',
    interval: '0',
    autostart: true,
});
```

I also have a pagination implemented:

```
    $('.jcarousel-pagination')
        .on('jcarouselpagination:active', 'a', function() {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        })
        .on('jcarouselpagination:inactive', 'a', function() {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        .jcarouselPagination();
```

That works so far, the carousel is moving slowly at every moment. But now the pagination buttons do not work anymore since the carousel is constantly inside a transition.

**What do I have to do in order to directly jump to the desired frame (with/without transition) when clicking one of the pagination items?**

JSFiddle see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sg9u5fLy/2)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is :

You can't use pagination when carousel do a transition. 
For example : 
here http://jsfiddle.net/2Kspn/18/
Try to click pagination when there is a transition. Pagination doesn't works.

or in your JsFiddle, put autostart at False, and try to click on transition. 
Its doesn't works.

So, I see somes solutions :

1. You can put a internal (at 1000 for example) in order to let pagination works between this interval. see here http://jsfiddle.net/2Kspn/15/
2. try to stop current transition, and force pagination.
   But in API, http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/api.html#api, we don't find a function like that. So we can add function.
   on event $('a').click().
   I can stop transition like that :

   $('.jcarousel ul').stop();

But we must do re-active transition.

so I do that :

```
$('.jcarousel ul').stop( true, true);
```

see here http://jsfiddle.net/sg9u5fLy/5/

But its not really what we want.

But maybe the good way ?

Hope that helps

Comment: +1 for the idea to stop the animation, I couldn't make the pagination work properly though. $('.jcarousel-control-next').click(function(){$('.jcarousel ul').stop(true, true);}); for the "next" and "previous" controls at least enables the user to navigate, but yeah it is an ugly workaround, moreover without smooth transition.